# Find and scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** everyone !
I am coding a board based on bootstrap3. There's a database filled with the sound infos and I'm creating divs from it. I'd like to add a search bar which find the element in the page and scroll to it.
I've already looked on jquery.scrollTo or javascript but I can't find how to do it !

Here's the search form I'd like to use :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And here's what the body looks like :

```
  echo "<div id='EPsound".$j."' name='".$name[$j]."' class='col-md-6'></br>"; //créer une div pchq son
            echo "<div class='sound center-block'>";
                echo "<img src=".$artwork[$j]." class='img-thumbnail center-block' />";
                echo "<span>$name[$j]</span>";
                echo "<i class='fa fa-play fa-3x play' onclick='$onclickplay'></i>";
                echo "<i class='fa fa-plus fa-3x plus' onclick='$onclickqueue'></i>";
            echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
```

**Thank you** so much for your help !

Comment: User will enter a name?

Comment: yes! like "Jeff Beck", then hit the Search button, and it will scroll to the appropriate div !

Comment: I think you should see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grab all the result containing the name
var list = $('.sound span'); // you should add a better scope

// Whenever user type in the input field...
$('.navbar-form input').on('keyup', function (e) {
   var regex = new RegExp(e.currentTarget.value, 'ig');

   // ...try to find if any element is matching typed text
   for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i += 1) {
     list[i].name.toLowerCase().match(regex) && list[i].scrollIntoView();
     break; // stop when found
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank's ! How do I implement this ?

Comment: I've found this : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/ but I'm getting trouble in implementing it !

Comment: I added some comments

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

If you are looking for a pure JavaScript solution, you could make use of the

```
scrollIntoView()
```

method.

To use it, you would need the 'element' on which you want to apply it. Hence, you would apply it as such:

```
document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView();
```

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/yYq39/1/

These method just brings the said element into focus immediately. So the overall effect from a user's perspective is not all that nice!!!

JQuery:

If you are looking for a smooth scroll to the said element, you could make use of Jquery's ScrollTop function:

You would use it this way:

```
$("#btnScroll").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#block2").offset().top }, 500);    
});
```

You can have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ak6L/

Hope this helps!!!